# Facebook page plugin width not applying

Tags: facebook, plugins, width

I have the following code set up on my page used to display the facebook plugin:

```
<div class="fb-page" data-hide-cover="true" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bikefinders" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true" data-width="280" style="float: left; margin: 10px;">
```

This worked fine until a couple of days ago. Now for some reason it is stuck on width 180px it seems - yet in the code it says 280px. Anyone know why this is? Check it out here: [www.bikefinder.no](http://bikefinder.no) (Plugin left side of pic).

Thanks for input!

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation on [Page Plugin doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) says under the heading **Adaptive Width**:

- Probably your container is `0 px` or `display: none` at the time of page load.
- The plugin tries to get to a minimum width, `180px` in this case
- So, if you ensure your container has `wdith >= configured_width`, it should work.

Code:

```
<div style="min-width: 180px">
    <div class="fb-page" data-hide-cover="true" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/bikefinders" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true" data-width="180" style="float: left; margin: 10px;">
</div>
```

`// min-width would ensure its 180px or greater`

Answer (score 0):

It checks parent (container) width, which overrides data-width attribute. 
You can wrap it inside a fixed-width div, for example.

```
<div style="width:300px">
<!--Page plugin's width will be 300px no matter what you set in data-width-->
  <div class="fb-page" ... 

</div>
```

By the way, the container and its parents should be visible during page loading otherwise it will be read as 0.

You can read more details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin)